# "Next" button custom keyboard Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I've created a custom keyboard using Objective-C. However, I'm stuck on a certain feature and that is being able to implement a "Next" button like that already available on the stock iOS keyboard. (I've attached a screen shot of the stock iOS keyboard below).

Here is my keyboard view controller code that connects my button voids to the actual keyboard :

```
-(void)addGesturesToKeyboard{
    [self.keyboard.globeSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.keyboard.planA addTarget:self action:@selector(execPlanA) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // what I want to implement -> [self.keyboard.planA addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.keyboard.planB addTarget:self action:@selector(execPlanB) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.keyboard.planC addTarget:self action:@selector(execPlanC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

And here is my textFieldshouldReturn method that doesn't seem to be working with me :

```
-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
     NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you set text view delegate to viewController?

Comment: @Saeed-rz I don't think so no.. I want the keyboard to be able to change between textfields on any website just like the stock keyboard.